# Windows API PostMessage / GetMessage

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a small application using VB.net for sending out faxes.

I can get the faxes to send out without any problems, what I would like to do is check the progress of a fax as it is being sent.

To send the faxes, I am using Snappy Software. According to their OLH :

*Tracking Fax Progress

You can track the progress of a fax that is submitted to snappy fax for processing by using the AppWindow, AppMsgNumber and AutoJobID properties. 
Set the AppWindow property to the window handle of your application's window. 
Set the AppMsgNumber to your desired message number, usually WM_APP + (some number of your choosing).

Set the AutoJobID property to a unique integer id that you can use internally in your application to know which fax job is being referred to in the status messages snappy fax sends to your application.  Setup a message handler in your application to receive and process the message number set in AppMsgNumber sent from snappy fax to your window handle specified in AppWindow.

When a fax job has been started by snappy fax it will send a message to your application as follows:

PostMessage(AppWindow,AppMsgNumber,1,LParam(AutoJobId))

Note the wParam is 1 indicates that the job is now being started (transmission will begin), the job being referred to is sent in the lparam
When the fax job has completed with or without success, snappy fax will send a message to your application as follows:

PostMessage(AppWindow,AppMsgNumber,ErrorCode,LParam(AutojobId))*

My question is, basically this, can VB.NET do this sort of thing ?

If Snappy software sends messages to my application using PostMessage() does that mean I have to use GETMessage() to pick these up ?

Apologies if these are silly questions, but I am new to VB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd override `WndProc()` in your main Form (or whatever form you use with the `AppWindow` property).  In there you'd check `m.Msg` for the `AppMsgNumber` value, and then grab the `m.WParam` and `m.LParam` values.  Something like:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Const WM_APP As Integer = &H8000
    Private Const WM_FAXMSG As Integer = WM_APP + 9999 ' set by you, send this  in the `AppMsgNumber` parameter when you register for feedback

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_FAXMSG
                Dim Status As Integer = m.WParam.ToInt32
                Dim FaxID As Integer = m.LParam.ToInt32
                Debug.Print("Status: " & Status)
                Debug.Print("FaxID: " & FaxID)
        End Select

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

End Class
```